# Proper style to implement control flow in python loop

Tags: python

I am not sure if the title of this question is correct or even the right question to ask (sorry if this is a duplicate).

What is the best (most pythonic) way to manage control flow in a loop in python, I specifically want to skip over items in a filter list. Here are my two approaches:

Idea 1:

```
items=["a","b","c","x","b"]
filterList=["x","y","z"]
for i in items:
    if i in filterList:
        continue

    ... Code for working with i
```

Idea 2:

```
items=["a","b","c","x","b"]
filterList=["x","y","z"]
for i in items:
    if i not in filterList:
        ... Code for working with i
```

Is one of these two styles more pythonic or readable than the other?

Edit 1:
One thing to note is that items will potentially have duplicates, updated code to reflect this.

Comment: This question is a bit opinion based but I find the second variant more readable. Note that none of these methods are the best performing solutions to your problem though. You can get more performance by converting both `list`s to `set`s and use set difference (e.g. `set(items) - set(filterList)`) to find the exact items you want to process as the first step. This only works if `items` contains no duplicates.

Comment: The performance benefit is from using a set instead of the second list, since that's the one you're doing slow membership tests on. There is no performance gain from converting the first list to a set also, unless you specifically want to avoid iterating over duplicates.

Comment: @kaya3 Right, but it lets you get rid of the `if` statement, making it more readable.

Comment: Yes, there are possible benefits besides performance.

Comment: Didnt know about `sets`, I am relatively new to python, I will have to review this! Also alas, `items` will contain duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use list comprehension:

```py
items = ...
filterList = ...

filtered_items = (i for i in items if i not in filterList)

for i in filtered_items:
   do the thing
```

Comment: With regards to performance how does this compare to using `set`s as mentioned in the comments of the question?

Comment: @Zexelon I didn't post this answer, but to answer your question: If you only convert `filterList` to a `set` the performance will be the same because of the cheaper lookups (`O(1)` vs `O(n)`). List comprehension method also allows you to keep duplicates in the original (`items`) list.